# How can I reference the getNext props in react-native by javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a cokebase like that, I wanna let callback render function in map reference the getNext props, how could I do it?

```
const render = ({ photoURL }) => {
  return(
    <Image key={photoURL} resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1}} source={{uri: photoURL}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 20, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "flex-end", justifyContent: "center"}}>
        <Button icon={{ name: "heart", type: "evilicon", color: "#ff0000", size: 70 }} backgroundColor="transparent" onPress={getNext} />
        <Button icon={{ name: "close-o", type: "evilicon", color: "#ff0000", size: 70 }} backgroundColor="transparent" onPress={getNext} />
      </View>
    </Image>
  )
}
//const { image, view } = styles

const Picture = ({ PHOTO_URLS, getNext}) => {

  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Carousel delay={2000} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#ff1493" }} pageInfo autoplay={false} onAnimateNextPage={(p) => console.log(p)} >
        {PHOTO_URLS.map(render)}
      </Carousel> 
    </View>
  )
}

export { Picture }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call another function that passes the `required parameters` down to it. Something like below

```
 { PHOTO_URLS.map((arg) => render(arg, getNext)) }
```